# Replace comma with "_" underscore in python bigrams

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a list of lists. I am able to generate the bigrams within the inner list and it looks like below:

> [[('bacteria', 'agricultur'), ('agricultur', 'soil'), ('soil', 'presenc'), ('presenc', 'sampl')],[('bacteria', 'agricultur'), ('agricultur', 'soil'), ('soil', 'presenc'), ('presenc', 'sampl')],[('nodul', 'uragensi')], [('nodul', 'stem'), ('stem', 'nodul')], [('deform', 'morphoid')]]

Now, I need to replace the comma within the bigram tuple to that with the underscore which I am unable to do. So, the result should look like

> [[(bacteria_agricultur), (agricultur_soil), (soil_presenc), (presenc_sampl)],[(bacteria_agricultur), (agricultur_soil), (soil_presenc), (presenc_sampl)],[(nodul_uragensi)], [(nodul_stem), (stem_nodul)], [('deform'_'morphoid')]]

When I use join it gives me error

```
texts = ["_".join(word) for word in texts]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

How can I produce the above output? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a nested list comprehension:

```
In [446]: [['_'.join(y) for y in x] for x in lst]
Out[446]: 
[['bacteria_agricultur', 'agricultur_soil', 'soil_presenc', 'presenc_sampl'],
 ['bacteria_agricultur', 'agricultur_soil', 'soil_presenc', 'presenc_sampl'],
 ['nodul_uragensi'],
 ['nodul_stem', 'stem_nodul'],
 ['deform_morphoid']]
```

If you insist on the parentheses, you can create single-element tuples as well:

```
In [447]: [[('_'.join(y), ) for y in x] for x in lst]
Out[447]: 
[[('bacteria_agricultur',),
  ('agricultur_soil',),
  ('soil_presenc',),
  ('presenc_sampl',)],
 [('bacteria_agricultur',),
  ('agricultur_soil',),
  ('soil_presenc',),
  ('presenc_sampl',)],
 [('nodul_uragensi',)],
 [('nodul_stem',), ('stem_nodul',)],
 [('deform_morphoid',)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NewData=[]
for bigrams in lists:
    for grams in bigrams:
        NewData.append(str(grams).replace("'","").replace(", ","_")))
```